# How to change the default cookie name `django_language` set by `set_language()` in Django?

Tags: python, django, default, django-i18n, django-cookies

I could set and use [set_language()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view) as shown below:

```py
# "core/urls.py"

...

urlpatterns += [
    path("i18n/", include("django.conf.urls.i18n")) # Here
]
```

Now, I want to change the default cookie name `django_language` below considering the security because users can easily know that **Django** is used for the website:

[image]

So, how can I change the default cookie name `django_language`?

Answer (score 0):

By setting [LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#language-cookie-name) in `settings.py` as shown below, you can change the default cookie name `django_language` set by [set_language()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view):

```py
# "core/settings.py"

LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME = "mylang"
```

Then, you can change it to `mylang` as shown below:

[image]